# Cómo Pasar fecha seleccionada de un input por URL

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente estructura.

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Cierre de Caja</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label>Fecha de Cierre</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha_cierre" id="fecha_cierre">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a class="btn btn-success" id="btnActualizar" href="../reportes/cierre_caja.php?fecha="><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Generar Cierre</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    </div>        
  </div>
```

donde necesito pasar por la url la variable "fecha_cierre".

el resultado deberia ser:

```
http://localhost/sistema/reportes/cierre_caja.php?fecha=20-02-2018
```

¿Alguna solución ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente escuche el evento `click` del botón , cuando se produzca ,modifica el `href` de su `<a>` , añadiendo el valor actual la fecha elegida en el `input` como desea que se produzca la redirección no se añade el `preventDefault()`

```
$(function() {
   $('#btnActualizar').on('click', function(event) {
      //Obtenemos la URL de cierre y le concatenamos al valor actual de href
      let fecha = $('#fecha_cierre').val();
      // asignamos el atributo href a lo que tiene actualmente
      //$(this).attr('href')  más la fecha obtenida del input
      $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+fecha);
   });
});
```

Comment: Disculpe la ignorancia estimado, me perdí cuando hizo referencia a modificar el href.

Comment: @JohnL la idea es que con `$(this).attr('href')` se obtiene el valor actual de `href` de su enlace y con `$(this).attr('href','aquiasignanuevovalor)` se asigna el valor para dicho atributo. lo que se hace es setear el atributo con lo que se tenía antes, pero a este se le concatena la fecha del input.

Comment: funciono. después de tanto rato intentando funciono, muchísimas gracias estimado.

Comment: @JohnL qué bueno, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Empecemos por lo siguiente:  Si quieres pasar un parámetro vía URL a un script php, tienes que usar los métodos `$.get` o `$.post` de jQuery (asumiendo que estás usando jQuery, de lo contrario la respuesta sería diferente).

Pero en ese caso, lo recomendable sería:

```
$.post("http://localhost/sistema/reportes/cierre_caja.php",
       {fecha:$("#fecha_cierre").val()},
       function(data){ .... hacer algo con 'data' .... }
       );
```

De esta forma, cuando ejecutes un evento `click()` o cualquier otro, y en ese invoques este código, usando el método `_POST`, formarás un URL como lo deseas en la forma: `http://urldeseado.php?parametro=Valor&parametro=Valor`

Espero que te ayude.